# как сделать так чтобы блок перестал двигаться вниз после достижения определенной точки

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

Я пытаюсь заставить div «box» перестать двигаться по экрану и остаться сразу после конца дива «banner»

как это возможно?

```js
$(function() {
  $('.banner').hide().slideDown(800);
  $('.banner h1').hide().show().addClass('animateText')
  $('.box').hide()
  var $win = $(window);

  $win.on("scroll", function() {
    var top = $win.scrollTop();
    $('.banner h1').css({
      'transform': 'rotate(' + top + 'deg)'
    })

    if (top > 150) {
      $('.banner h1').css({
        'opacity': 0
      })
      $('.banner p').slideDown(800);
      $('.banner h2').css({
        'left': top * 1.2 + 'px'
      })
      $('.box').slideDown(600)
      $('.box').css({
        'transform': 'translateY(' + top / 2 + 'px)'
      })

    } else if (top < 400) {
      $('.banner h1').css({
        'opacity': 1
      })
      $('.banner p').slideUp(800);
      $('.banner h2').css({
        'left': '-400px',
        'transition': '600ms'
      })
      $('.box').slideUp(1000);

    }

    //типа как тут:
    if (top > $('.banner').outerHeight()) {
      $('.box').stopRightWhereYouAre()
    }
  });
});
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-family: arial;
}

.banner {
  background: linear-gradient(to left, black 50%, white 50%);
  height: 100vh;
}

.banner h1 {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 300px;
  padding-top: 250px;
  margin: 0;
  font-weight: bold;
  background: linear-gradient(to right, black 50%, white 50%);
  -webkit-background-clip: text;
  -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
}

.animateText {
  animation: slide 2000ms ease-in-out;
}

@keyframes slide {
  0% {
    margin-left: -800px
  }
  50% {
    font-size: 350px;
  }
  100% {
    font-size: 300px;
    text-align: center;
  }
}

.banner p {
  color: white;
  width: 450px;
  margin-left: 60%;
  margin-top: -17%;
  font-size: 1.5em;
  display: none;
}

h2 {
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 100px;
  color: black;
  top: 250px;
  left: -400px;
  position: absolute;
}

.box {
  background-color: black;
  height: 60vh;
  width: 40%;
  margin-top: -400px;
  padding-top: 100px;
}

.h {
  margin-bottom: 300vh
}

.box p {
  color: white;
  width: 400px;
  font-size: 1.5em;
  margin: 0;
  margin-left: 50px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="banner">
  <h1>HELLO</h1>
  <div class="rotate">
    <h2>DESIGN</h2>
  </div>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure
    dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
</div>
<div class="box">
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure
    dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
</div>
<div class="h"></div>
```

Comment: в нужный момент задайте этому блоку `position: fixed`, с желаемыми координатами

Comment: точно!!! спасибо

Comment: @Дмытрык что-то не получается.. можете продемонстрировать на примере?

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/896550/%D0%A1%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BF%D1%82-%D1%84%D0%B8%D0%BA%D1%81%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B8-%D1%8D%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B0-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BA%D1%80%D1%83%D1%82%D0%BA%D0%B5-%D0%BD%D0%B5-%D1%81%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8B%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%B5%D1%82-%D0%9F%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B5-%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%B9%D1%82%D0%B8-%D0%BE%D1%88%D0%B8%D0%B1%D0%BA%D1%83

Answer (score 1):

```js
const elem = document.getElementById('elem');
document.addEventListener('scroll', handlerScroll)

function handlerScroll () {
const positions = elem.getBoundingClientRect();
if (positions.top <=0) {
 elem.setAttribute('style', 'position:fixed; top:0;')
}
}
```

```css
body {
display: flex;
flex-direction: column;
align-items: center;
height: 200vh;
}
#elem {
position: absolute;
top: 200px;
width: 100px;
height: 100px;
border: 1px solid;
background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<div id="elem"></div>
```

Так же, это можно сделать через добавление класса

Answer (score 1):

`position: sticky;` - хорошее быстрое решение, но с поддержкой браузерами у него пока проблемы, поэтому на продакшене лучше пойти через js, тем более, что понадобится 10 строчек ванилы.

```js
const node = document.getElementById('menu_sticky'),
  nodeOffs = node.offsetTop;
window.addEventListener('scroll', function() {
  let scrollPos = (window.pageYOffset || document.documentElement.scrollTop || document.body.scrollTop || 0);
  if (scrollPos > nodeOffs) {
    node.classList.add('_stickied');
  } else {
    node.classList.remove('_stickied');
  }
});
```

```css
body {
  padding: 300px 0 0 0;
  margin:0;
  height: 200vh;
}
.menu._sticky {
  height: 50px;
  width:100%;
  background-color:red;
}

.menu._sticky._stickied {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}
```

```html
<nav class="menu _sticky" id="menu_sticky"></nav>
```