# Скрипт фиксации элемента при прокрутке не срабатывает. Помогите найти ошибку

Tags: javascript, jquery, css3, html5

Пытаюсь зафиксировать кнопку "Позвонить" при прокрутке страницы. Нашла скрипт, который добавляет класс выбранному элементу при прокрутке. Вставляю этот код перед закрывающим body:

```
<script>
  $(window).scroll(function(){
if ($(window).scrollTop()>50) {
    $('.new').addClass('scrolled');
}
else {
    $('.new').removeClass('scrolled')
} });
</script>
```

Добавленному скриптом классу прописываю стили:

```
.new > .scrolled {
    position: fixed;
    top: 1%;
    left: 50%;}
```

html такой:

```
<center class="new">
        <div id="такой-то" align="center">
          <p>*Тут отображается кнопка, которую нужно зафиксировать при прокрутке*</p>
        </div>
        <script> код виджета</script> 
        <p style="text-align: center;" id="contacts2"> тут просто текст</p>
      </center>
```

И не работает у меня ничего :(

В примере, откуда брала код, все работает, а у меня на странице - нет. О js у меня совсем поверхностное представление. Подскажите, что неправильно?

Пыталась также добавить класс непосредственно div id="такой-то", но тоже не работает.

Как исправить?

Спасибо!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы добавляете/удаляете класс `scrolled` у элемента с классом `new`, а хотите влиять на элемент внутри `new`.

```
.new.scrolled #такой-то {
  ...
}
```

или просто

```
#такой-то {
  ...
}
```

Вероятно, опечатка - пропущена точка перед `new`:

```
$('new').removeClass('scrolled')
```

```js
$(window).scroll(function() {
  if ($(window).scrollTop() > 50) {
    $('.new').addClass('scrolled');
  } else {
    $('.new').removeClass('scrolled');
  }
});
```

```css
.new.scrolled #button {
  position: fixed;
  top: 1%;
  left: 50%;
}
.block{
  border:1px solid black;
  background:lightgreen;
  height:100px;
  width:100px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<center class="new">
  <div id="button" align="center">
    <p>*Тут отображается кнопка, которую нужно зафиксировать при прокрутке*</p>
  </div>
  <script>
    //код виджета
  </script>
  <p style="text-align: center;" id="contacts2"> тут просто текст</p>
</center>

<div class="block"></div><br/>
<div class="block"></div><br/>
<div class="block"></div><br/>
<div class="block"></div><br/>
<div class="block"></div><br/>
<div class="block"></div><br/>
<div class="block"></div><br/>
<div class="block"></div><br/>
<div class="block"></div><br/>
<div class="block"></div><br/>
```

Comment: Спасибо огромное! Завтра буду сверять свой код с тем, что Вы написали. Сегодня уже мозг сломан окончательно.

Comment: РАБОТАЕТ!! УРА!