# Bootstrap Sticky-top Sidebar меню

Tags: bootstrap, bootstrap4

Есть ли возможность в Bootstrap 4 сделать sticky-top sidebar таким образом, чтобы sticky-top пропадало после скрола до какой-то определенной точки, чтобы после этой точки меню в сайдбаре скролилось как и остальной контент?

Answer (score 0):

`position: sticky;` - хорошее быстрое решение, но с поддержкой браузерами у него пока проблемы, поэтому на продакшене лучше пойти через js, тем более, что понадобится 10 строчек ванилы.

```js
const node = document.getElementById('menu_sticky'),
  nodeOffs = node.offsetTop;
window.addEventListener('scroll', function() {
  let scrollPos = (window.pageYOffset || document.documentElement.scrollTop || document.body.scrollTop || 0);
  if ((scrollPos > nodeOffs) && scrollPos < nodeOffs*2) {
    node.classList.add('_stickied');
  } else {
    node.classList.remove('_stickied');
  }
});
```

```css
body {
  padding: 300px 0 0 0;
  margin:0;
  height: 200vh;
}
.menu._sticky {
  height: 50px;
  width:100%;
  background-color:red;
}

.menu._sticky._stickied {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}
```

```html
<nav class="menu _sticky" id="menu_sticky"></nav>
```

[Источник](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/896376/%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D1%81%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D1%87%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%8B-%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BA-%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BB-%D0%B4%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%B3%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C%D1%81%D1%8F-%D0%B2%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B7-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B5-%D0%B4%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%BE%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B9/896568#896568)